# ng2 dragula | After droping element to add some new data in it as per JSON value

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, dom-events, ng2-dragula

After using the ng2 Dragula library I found myself to do some interesting fact in it.

Like after dragging element from one container to another the Element should expand its data feature to show the part like Droplist, HTML input form etc.

Basically to check the element the feature after dropping.

Answer (score 0):

Following code defines the *show hide* feature while dropping the field to another container.
Here I have checked the length and display same.

```
 <div class="col-md-3" [dragula]='"main"' [dragulaModel]='GroupB'>
      <div *ngFor="let item of GroupB">{item.User}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" [dragula]='"main"' [dragulaModel]='GroupA'>
      <div *ngFor="let item of GroupA">{{item.User}}
        <br>
        <span *ngIf="item.arithmatic?.length > 0">
          <h6>Arithmatic Operation
            <select>
              <option *ngFor=" let arithmaticList of item.arithmatic "> {{arithmaticList}}</option>
            </select>
            <i class="fa fa-navicon handle "></i>
          </h6>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```